# Not able to install golangci-lint in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vim, golang, vim-plugin

On installing vim-go in my Ubuntu 18.04 but on following the steps I am getting an error as shown below :-

```
vim-go: Error installing github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@master: go: found github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint in github.com/golangci/golangci-lint v1.27.1-0.20200518075657-2c45244db801
vim-go: # github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint
vim-go: /mnt/d/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
vim-go: 
vim-go: installing finished!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How do I fix this error? Everything else if working fine.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can show us which commands you have given before you received this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install gcc compiler. Open Terminal and execute below command to install development libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Yeah it solved the problem.

Comment: You can marked it resolved.